# gstreamer pipeline hangs when sink property sync is set to 0

Tags: gstreamer

I am on gstreamer 1.2.4.

I have developed a video sink based on xvimagesink.

When I set the sync property of the sink to 0 the pipeline hangs after displaying a few frames.

I used the following pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! myvideosink sync=0
```

I noticed that even the decoder stops receiveing frames.
This issue occurs even with videotestsrc

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! myvideosink sync=0
```

This does not occur with xvimagesink.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your sink not handling the pipeline clock appropriately.

Comment: I havent handled clocks explicitly. I thought pipeline does that for us. While debugging i found that, if I add a few ms sleep (>5 ms) in the show_frame function, it works. Does this help?

Comment: That's irrelevant here as sync=false is used and nothing else is syncing to the clock in that pipeline.

Comment: Without having access to the code of your custom video sink or more details it will be impossible to tell what exactly is wrong. As long as you implement a subclass of GstBaseSink and use the API correctly, it should behave the same way as xvimagesink (which you say does not have this problem). So it's likely a bug in your code.